# SQLite3 in Symfony3 without doctrine

Tags: database, symfony

Is there a specific way to use sqlite3 in symfony without using doctrine?

I just want to do basic operations. And tried including the classes in the directory structure but it is not able to find SQLite3 class.

Any suggestions? I am very tight on time constraint.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php

Comment: me too i have the same problem i want to use the function new \SQLite3 inside symfony but it give an error response : 
Attempted to load class "SQLite3" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?
if you found any solutions please tell me thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine allow to use sqlite if you define path in doctrine dbal in config.

> [How to use sqlite database on symfony2 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551931/how-to-use-sqlite-database-on-symfony2-project)

but Doctrine is not integral part of Symfony, so you can drop Doctrine from your project and use sqlite like in pure Php.

You can use exaples form docs:

> http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php

proposed by Jason Roman in comment. It is simple, but I suggest to create your own service for operation on sqlite or simply use PDO.

> http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php

Comment: Thanks for the link but I am looking out for symfony3.

Comment: It do not make any difference in your case. Tried you use these methods in SF3?