# symfony CLI, how to open ports on mac?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony

I'm trying out Symfony for the first time, so I installed all the stuff required to create ant run apps, but I'm having problems with this port `5432`.

Any ideas how to open it? I'm using Symfony CLI to develop locally, searched for solution everywhere.

[image: this is the errors im having trouble with]

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Comment: Please share more details - what do you mean by "create ant run apps"? What's the exact problem you are facing? Can you share the error messages in text form, along with your attempts to resolve the errors?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error message (although cut) is saying that there's no such (PostgreSQL) server running. You need to install PostgreSQL server (or have one on the remote location), then Symfony to the correct hostname/ip + port.

Verify:

- PostgreSQL is installed on some location (for you that'd be [MacOS installer](https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx)) unless you have a remote server. ([tutorial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial.html))
- you have the correct IP or hostname
- you haven't mistyped the port (5432 vs 5423)
- you can access such IP or hostname by `ping` (e.g. `ping 127.0.0.1`) and `telnet` (e.g. `telnet 127.0.0.1 5432`)

Then if you are sure the DB is installed, running and accessible make sure your configuration also matches it properly.

Alternatively, since PostgreSQL is quite heavy if you are beginner, try using [SQLite3](https://sqlite.org) which is a file- or memory-based database (does not require any server) with [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9552102/5994041).

Comment: but in symfony documentation they state that symfony CLI is all i need to run it locally, so it suppose to have it preinstalled isint it?

Comment: @realmacas [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) is one piece of software, however [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) is a different one (unrelated). If you have set up Symfony to require PostgreSQL, then it'll most likely crash when it isn't running. Perhaps [sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9552102/5994041) would be better for you if you don't want to install the server.